# PHP & JS - Cookie value in If Statement causes Bug

Tags: javascript, php, html, setcookie, confirm

I am trying to make a function with HTML, JS and PHP that does the following:

1. When a HTML "button" is pressed, it gives values to a `$_GET` array;
2. When those values exist on the `$_GET` array it pops up a JavaScript confirm window;
3. If the user presses "OK" the JS gives to a `$_COOKIE` array the value of `true`. If the user presses "CANCEL" JS gives to `$_COOKIE` array the value of `false`;
4. For last the `$_COOKIE` array is checked with PHP, and if it is `true` it does something. Otherwise it doesn't do nothing.

Where is the code for each step:

```
// STEP 1
<a href="page.php?remove=true&id-organ=1">Remove</a>

// STEP 2 AND 3
if (isset($_GET['remove']) && isset($_GET['id-organ'])) {
       echo '
           <script>
                var option = confirm("REMOVE?");
                if (option == true) {
                    document.cookie = "option = true";
                } else {
                    document.cookie = "option = false";
                }
           </script>
       ';
}

// STEP 4
if ($_COOKIE['option'] == true) {
    echo '
        <script>
            window.alert("ORGAN WAS REMOVED!\n");
        </script>
    ';
    
}
```

**If JS Confirm Window "OK" is pressed everything works fine, awesome, with no problem.**

**If JS Confirm Window "CANCEL" is pressed, the STEP 4 if statement happens anyway.**

- I have tried to `console.log(option)` which is false for CANCEL
  button.
- I have tried to `echo $_COOKIE['option']` wihch is also false
  for CANCEL button.

This make no sense being literally against all"programming physics". . .

Can someone tell me why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way for this type of functionality?

Comment: PHP runs on server, JavaScript on the client, they do not run at the same time. So how are step 2 and 3 running?

Comment: Okay, when you learn what you are doing is going to require a form submission back to the server, you will understand it. The PHP will execute the code and then the page loads. It does not sit there and wait for the JavaScript to execute. (And I did not downvote)

Comment: So why does true value work fine and false value doens't? I am sorry foi saying that about downvote ... If it wasn´t you then I really mean it. I am sorry.

Comment: I would go back to the drawing board and learn about `AJAX` and separating your PHP, HTML and your Javascript. Since PHP is processed BEFORE Javascript is even sent to the browser to be ran, you will get results that you aren't expecting. So learning how to separate them will allow you to learn best practices as well limit the weird bugs that will popup when you combine them together.

Comment: because you already have a cookie set the second time you ran it?

Comment: I thought that, and I decided to print the value of the cookie before entering the second if statement. It haves the value of false, SO it makes no sense to enter in the if statement ...

Comment: unless you are reloading the page, there is NO way for it to go into the code. The PHP code is going to run fully from to bottom and produce the page that the JavaScript is on. They do not interact.... So when you set the cookie in the JavaScript the `if ($_COOKIE['option'] == true) {` has already run.

Comment: I am reloading the entire page, I am not putting the entire code that I have so that it doesn't get messy. The page is being reloaded on STEP 1. The STEP 4 if works fine if the value of the cookie is true. So it means it is not beeing runned before.

Comment: @Grinnex.I do not know PHP, but not sure how cookie string matches a boolean true.

Comment: @epascarello - Initially I thought that too. However to be a string the cookie assignment needed to have quotation marks like this "true".
The problem it's definitely on the Cookie variable . . . Just don't know how to fix it. I tried severall approaches and when it receives the false value it still enters the if statement. This makes no sense. . .

Comment: The cookie value you set in JS is _always_ a string. But your comparison in PHP is wrong - because there, you are _not_ comparing with a string. The _text_ values `'true'` and `'false'` are _both_ truth-y in PHP - `'true' == true` and `'false' == true` both yield `true`. What you need here, is `if ($_COOKIE['option'] == 'true')` (or even with `===`, to make absolutely sure there is no ambiguity whatsoever.)

Comment: @CBroe you are awesome! Congratulations! Your solution is working! However I was forced to change the If stament to `false` because the feedback functions were the opposite. Beeing `true` not entering on the if and `false` entering on the If .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie value you set in JS is always a string. (Cookie content *is* mere text, by definition. No one stops you to *interpret* that value as something else, *after* you received it in string form - you could for example set a JSON-encoded object as the cookie value. But that doesn’t change the fact, that the value of the cookie itself, is and will always be text.)

> ```
> if ($_COOKIE['option'] == true)
> ```

Your comparison in PHP is wrong here - because here, you are *not* comparing with a string.

The *text* values `'true'` and `'false'` are both truth-y in PHP - `'true' == true` and `'false' == true` both yield true.

What you need here, is `if ($_COOKIE['option'] == 'true')` (or even with `===`, to make absolutely sure there is no ambiguity whatsoever.)